# When I use JQuery slider to unhide images it doesn't work when moving the slider really fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I have a jquery slider that I am using to unhide a list of images.
A synopsis of my code is as follows.

I have a list of images that are hidden using css ' display:none'

Each image has an id with a number in it that matches this pattern:

```
#cloud-10

#cloud-20

#cloud-30 ... etc
```

I am using JQuery slider and when I move the slider it triggers a counter that increments and this counter is used in a line of JQuery code that looks like this:

```
$('#cloud-' + i).css( {'display':'block'}  );
```

The good news is when you move the slider very slow it works. The problem is when you just move the slider to the right as fast as possible it doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Here is a fiddle with complete code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8yNL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slide()`-function of the slider is not triggered for every value. It triggers all X ms only. So your apprach wont work.
What you can do is: You can display all divs where the number is equal or less the slider value.

```
$('[id^="cloud"]').each(function(){
    var index = parseInt(this.id.replace('cloud-', ''));
    if(index <= ui.value)
         $(this).show();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8yNL/3/
Well - the fact that all your ids starting with 'cloud' makes this example fail. You should numer the imgs in another way.

And you should clean up your code!

// Edit: To avoid the mess with the ids, try to group all images in one div with a ceartain id. Then you can access all elements lower the slider value using `$('#divId img:lt('+ui.value/10+')')`

Comment: Thanks for this but in my desire to understand the problem better what do you mean it 'triggers all X ms only' ?

Comment: X Milliseconds where X is a number I dont know (just as fast as the browser wants - something...)

Comment: Sorry, That's what I figured you meant ( common sense)  but it took me a second to understand why my code wouldn't work and yours did even with that being the problem so I was quick to type a comment

Comment: As far as cleaning up the div/id's I was actually going to write a loop to dynamically create all that stuff but I brute-forced it just to get the ball rolling.

Comment: Tell me when it works ;) and post the working fiddle so other people can see the working code